# Saving bytecode of a Class (to SharedObject or database)

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript

**NOTE: I want to save the actual bytecode for the AS3 class, NOT an instance of it!**

A class is being loaded in externally and extracted via a `URLLoader` and then `Loader.loadBytes`. A single Class is then extracted out of that Application Domain and used in the project.

Now, rather than saving the entire Loader (either via `SharedObject` or other means of storage) is it possible to "extract out" the bytecode of the needed class and all dependencies, which can then be "injected" back into an empty shell or something to be reused when needed?

Comment: This seems like a bizarre request to me.  What is your use case?

Comment: Are you trying to do caching? Flash player handles cashing for you, so you don't have to!

Comment: @Flextras I stumbled across a project which allows you to write the logic to control ["virtual robots" written in AS3](http://code.google.com/p/as3bots/) This logic is currently loaded in at runtime nearly via the process described above (it actually uses `FileReference` rather than a `URLLoader`).

I want to "store" different logic to avoid having to re-load it in every time I run the program, as well as keep different "versions" of the same logic stored.

Though, I can definitely see this system having uses elsewhere as well.

Comment: Why going after class? If you need plugin system, load swf with classes. There are ways to get class list from swf, then you can instantiate them.

Answer (score 1):

So you would like to eval(some code)? There is no eval() in AS3, but this might help you:
http://danielmclaren.com/2008/09/21/eval-in-as3-tips-for-executing-dynamic-actionscript

You can also save class in AMF like suggested by 3Devil.

Example:

```
package vos
{
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;
    import org.flixel.FlxPath;

    public class ActionVO extends Object
    {
        public var pid:uint;
        public var cid:uint;
        public var action:String;
        public var data:*;

    }
}
```

And the class you are saving shared object you need

```
registerClassAlias( "org.flixel::FlxPath", FlxPath );
registerClassAlias( "org.flixel::FlxPoint", FlxPoint );
registerClassAlias( "VO::ActionVO", ActionVO );
```

and saving:

```
var byteArray:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
byteArray.writeObject(data);
shared.data.byteArray = byteArray;
```

..and loading:

```
var ba:ByteArray = shared.data.byteArray
ba.uncompress();
var vo:ActionVO = ba.readObject() as ActionVO;
```

And there you have vo (simple value object class, including more complex class FlxPath)

Comment: As mentioned earlier, that will save all the "values" of an object, but it will not store the bytecode or instructions of the Functions.

Comment: no, that is not true. My example was probably pretty bad :) Important part was 

registerClassAlias( "org.flixel::FlxPath", FlxPath ); 

That makes it possible to use values and also functions inside the class.

Comment: ..well, you have new note:"NOTE: I want to save the actual bytecode for the AS3 class" ..you are right, you cant load new class and use it as, well new class. Eval is close, but not the same, and there is no eval() in AS3.

Comment: hmm, that "virtual robots" in your comments was kind of interesting! My adhd eye couldnt catch anything from there; no downloads, no source.. i did a quick look to blog, but there was too much everything else :) Can you tell more about that?

Comment: All the threads marked as "robot wars" on their blog have more details. http://dotbrighton.org/?tag=robot-wars I have only played with it once, but let me know if you still want more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using ByteArray.writeObject, which will save a reversable snapshot of object properties.

Comment: That will save the **instance** properties, not the actual class logic. Also, you would still need that class to exist in the current Application Domain in order to restore the instance to it's state anyway. ;)

Comment: What you are talking about in general are modules. Something I have used to instantiate different objects, sharing the same interface. I load the module, which basically is nothing but an instance of the desired sub class and then pass it to the main application, freeing the module after that. You don't need to have the class included, just the interface to make that class usable.